# Ability to send Application Invite via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I've discovered that via Graph Search, you are able to view who have visited 'location' such as the following:

https://www.facebook.com/search/765247923489561/visitors

or

People who visited Assembly Coffee

Is there any API that could make it possible to send a facebook app invite to these users?

Comment: Invites can only be send actively by a user of your app to their friends. (And that’s a good thing, because what you have in mind is just _spam_ in its very definition.)

Comment: Can page adminstrators send app invites to users?

Comment: No, they can not. If you want people who like a page to use your app, then just make a normal post on the timeline of the page telling them about it. If they’re interested, they’ll check it out.